# Nginx https very high connect time and is much slower (32 times) than Nginx http & 12 times slower than Apache https

Tags: apache, nginx, https, webserver, angular6

I have an Angular website with static assets of around 1.5 mb and gzipped it is around 400 kb, I have nginx as my webserver & reverse proxy to the API server, when I test nginx with Apache benchmark tool, I find huge drop in performance if I test the https site compared to the http (https is 10 times slower) & the cpu utilization & memory is not high at all (cpu 30% memory is only 1 mb!!)

I have been searching for hours & tried all possible enhancements but none worked, as far as I have read https shall not be that much slower on modern web servers (http around 1500 req/sec & https is 46 req/sec for nginx), this is mostly from the Nginx https very high connect time but I have no clue how to solve this.

Can someone advise how to improve this?

(Also to my surprise, Apache performs much better in both cases but doesn't respond if I set concurrent connections to more than 200) & this is not nginx vs apache I am just stating my situation.

***Important note:***

I am not comparing the 2 web servers that is not the point of this site, but generally they have comparable performance ***so if https in nginx is 10 times slower than Apache I feel that something is wrong in my Nginx configuration & I want to fix it.***

All test are on my windows machine i7 & 16 gb ram.

Nginx http only:

```
C:\Apache24\bin>ab -n 5000 -c 200 http://localhost:8100/abc/index.html?param=abc
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1826891 $>

Server Software:        nginx/1.15.4
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8100

Document Path:          /abc/index.html?param=abc
Document Length:        1099 bytes

Concurrency Level:      200
Time taken for tests:   3.246 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      6665000 bytes
HTML transferred:       5495000 bytes
Requests per second:    1540.32 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       129.843 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.649 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2005.12 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   1.3      0      16
Processing:    31   87  12.8     94     124
Waiting:        0   87  13.7     94     124
Total:         31   87  12.8     94     124

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     94
  66%     94
  75%     94
  80%     94
  90%     99
  95%    109
  98%    109
  99%    113
 100%    124 (longest request)
```

Nginx https (with http2 enabled)

```
C:\Apache24\bin>abs -n 5000 -c 200 https://localhost:8200/abc/index.html?param=abc
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1826891 $>

Server Software:        nginx/1.15.4
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8200
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,2048,256
TLS Server Name:        localhost

Document Path:          /abc/index.html?param=abc
Document Length:        1099 bytes

Concurrency Level:      200
Time taken for tests:   108.985 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      6780000 bytes
HTML transferred:       5495000 bytes
Requests per second:    45.88 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       4359.386 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       21.797 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          60.75 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       16 4201 506.8   4251    4755
Processing:     0   32  12.6     31      88
Waiting:        0   32  12.6     31      88
Total:         62 4232 506.9   4283    4800

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   4283
  66%   4342
  75%   4413
  80%   4439
  90%   4484
  95%   4547
  98%   4694
  99%   4727
 100%   4800 (longest request)
```

Compared to Apache http (here CPU is around 90 to 100% utilized)

```
C:\Apache24\bin>ab -n 5000 -c 200 http://localhost:6200/abc/index.html?param=abc
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.33
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            6200

Document Path:          /abc/index.html?param=abc
Document Length:        1099 bytes

Concurrency Level:      200
Time taken for tests:   1.781 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      6810000 bytes
HTML transferred:       5495000 bytes
Requests per second:    2806.99 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       71.251 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.356 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3733.51 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   1.6      0      16
Processing:    16   69  16.0     63     125
Waiting:        0   57  16.0     63     125
Total:         16   69  16.0     63     125

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     63
  66%     78
  75%     78
  80%     78
  90%     94
  95%     94
  98%     94
  99%    109
 100%    125 (longest request)
```

And Apache https is as follows (http 1.1) & note that http 1.1 in nginx didn't improve its performance:

```
C:\Apache24\bin>abs -n 5000 -c 200 https://localhost:7200/abc/index.html?param=abc

This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1826891 $>

Server Software:        Apache/2.4.33
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            7200
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,2048,256
TLS Server Name:        localhost

Document Path:          /abc/index.html?param=abc
Document Length:        1099 bytes

Concurrency Level:      200
Time taken for tests:   8.747 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      6810000 bytes
HTML transferred:       5495000 bytes
Requests per second:    571.60 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       349.894 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.749 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          760.27 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
            min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0  198  42.7    188     391
Processing:    62  145  39.1    140     385
Waiting:        0   76  28.3     78     250
Total:         62  343  63.0    331     615

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
50%    331
66%    369
75%    380
80%    389
90%    422
95%    465
98%    500
99%    536
100%    615 (longest request)
```

My nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8100;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

    server {
    listen       8200 ssl http2;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate      C:/nginx-1.13.12/conf/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  C:/nginx-1.13.12/conf/server.key;

        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 1;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_types
            text/css
            text/javascript
            text/xml
            text/plain
            text/x-component
            application/javascript
            application/json
            application/xml
            application/rss+xml
            font/truetype
            font/opentype
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject
            image/svg+xml;

        gzip_static on;

    location /ipo_reits/ {

        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        ## here we redirect to the homepage in case of nginx 404 
        try_files $uri $uri/ /ipo_reits/index.html;
        #    error_page 404 =301 /;
    }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass  https://localhost:7001/;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that this will help someone else, It seems that is related to nginx on windows issue, I wrongly assumed that the performance of nginx on windows & linux is similar but clearly it is not.

I have tried the benchmark again with nginx on Linux on the same machine & got excellent performance as shown below

```
ab -n 5000 -c 200 https://localhost:8200/abc/index?param=abc
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1706008 $>

Finished 5000 requests

Server Software:        nginx/1.10.3
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8200
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,2048,256

Document Path:          /abc/index?param=abc
Document Length:        1099 bytes

Concurrency Level:      200
Time taken for tests:   4.179 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      6825000 bytes
HTML transferred:       5495000 bytes
Requests per second:    1196.37 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       167.173 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.836 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1594.77 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       15  141 185.3    106    1322
Processing:     1   22  13.1     20      82
Waiting:        1   14   9.5     13      81
Total:         24  163 185.7    128    1351

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    128
  66%    142
  75%    148
  80%    155
  90%    208
  95%    260
  98%   1100
  99%   1164
 100%   1351 (longest request)
```

Also for sustained higher load & concurrency, performance was still the same:

```
ab -n 25000 -c 1000 https://localhost:8200/abc/index?param=abc
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1706008 $>

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 2500 requests
....
Completed 25000 requests
Finished 25000 requests


Server Software:        nginx/1.10.3
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8200
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,2048,256

Document Path:          /abc/index?param=abc
Document Length:        1099 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   20.149 seconds
Complete requests:      25000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      34125000 bytes
HTML transferred:       27475000 bytes
Requests per second:    1240.76 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       805.960 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.806 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1653.94 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        7  687 711.8    492    7694
Processing:     2   89  50.1     81     516
Waiting:        0   57  48.9     41     509
Total:         15  776 723.4    600    7756

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    600
  66%    812
  75%   1095
  80%   1186
  90%   1397
  95%   1631
  98%   3183
  99%   3442
 100%   7756 (longest request)
```

Answer (score -1):

Avoid Old Cipher Suites
HTTP/2 has a huge blacklist of old and insecure ciphers, so we must avoid them. Cipher suites are a bunch of cryptographic algorithms, which describe how the transferring data should be encrypted.

We will use a really popular cipher set, whose security was approved by Internet giants like CloudFlare. It does not allow the usage of MD5 encryption (which was known as insecure since 1996, but despite this fact, its use is widespread even to this day).

Open the following configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
Add this line after ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;.
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
```

Save the file, and exit the text editor.

Once again, check the configuration for syntax errors:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but that is not the point of the question at all, the configuration for the cipher suites is secure enough as per Nginx guides & in this test it is clear that both Nginx & Apache are using the same cipher suite:
`TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,2048,256`